# How to parse netstat output in a txt file and get all the remote ip addresses as variables according to PID?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, parsing, desktop-application

**Background**

The desktop WPF application that im trying to code requires allows me to select processes/applications currently running on the local machine and get the application name and PID and store it in a variable.
Every time the application loads after the user clicks a button after selecting a process, a `netstat -ano > C:\test.txt` is executed.

**Problem**

Is there a way to code it so that the application name and PID that was obtained earlier can be compared with the matched PID row in the `test.txt` file and then store the remote ip address into variable(s) or an array? Thanks.

Comment: See following : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/85dadf40-13ee-4b9c-9f0e-d7770b046902/capturing-the-output-of-netstat?forum=netfxnetcom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why have a text file at all? Here's how I would solve the problem, using a DataTable to store the data and collect it:

```
        //Create the process
        using (Process ns = new Process())
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {
                    new DataColumn("Protocol"),
                    new DataColumn("Local Address"),
                    new DataColumn("Foreign Address"),
                    new DataColumn("State"),
                    new DataColumn("PID"),
                    new DataColumn("Process Name"),
                });

            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("netstat.exe", "-ano");
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            ns.StartInfo = psi;
            // Run it, and read the results
            ns.Start();
            using (StreamReader r = ns.StandardOutput)
            {
                string output = r.ReadToEnd();
                ns.WaitForExit();

                //Parse those results into a DataTable, polling the Process info
                string[] lines = output.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);


                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    string[] elements = line.Split(' ');
                    if (elements.Length < 5) continue;
                    if (elements.Contains("Proto")) continue;

                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                    List<string> validElements = new List<string>();

                    //Weed out empty elements.
                    foreach (string element in elements)
                    {
                        //skip blanks
                        if (element.Trim() == "") continue;
                        validElements.Add(element);
                    }

                    foreach (string element in validElements)
                    {

                        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            // fill in the buckets. Note that UDP doesn't have a state
                            if (dr["Protocol"].ToString() == "UDP" && dc.ColumnName == "State") continue;

                            if (dr[dc] == DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                dr[dc] = element;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    dr["Process Name"] = Process.GetProcessById(int.Parse(dr["PID"].ToString())).ProcessName;
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
        }
```

And here's a short screencap of my resulting data:

[image]

Then I can do whatever I want to in code with that data. That's how I would do it, at least.